# disable automatic running of dhcpcd at startup

Tags: dhcp, boot, dhcpcd

I installed the DHCP client `dhcpcd` on Debian to run it **manually** on a given set of interfaces, but I see that at reboot `dhcpcd` tries to configure my *entire* set of interfaces. Not being able to do so, it assigns a zero-conf address to each interface and adds zero-conf routes too!

Is there a way to completely disable any automatic behavior of `dhcpcd`?

I just need to run it on a given interface and stay in the background to renew a DHCP lease whenever such lease expires. Nothing else.

Comment: Have you tried to systemctl disable dhcpcd.service?

Comment: Uhm... is that resilient to reboot?

Comment: Yes, `disable` stops it from starting, while `stop` stops a currently running process.

Answer (score 1):

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and change:

```
iface ethN inet dhcp
```

to

```
iface ethN inet manual
```

If your `interfaces` file doesn't have these lines, you should add them:

```
auto ethN
iface ethN inet manual
```

Comment: I don't have anything in there except for `auto lo\n
iface lo inet loopback`...

Comment: In that case you should add definitions for interfaces there.